# Codeigniter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

There is a bit of problem in my code which i am not able to solve.
I m using CI 1.7.2.
I have implemented the CI Pagination into the system correctly.
The results are displayed fine but the links in the pagination are not rendering correctly.

For eg. If i click on the page 2 then the results are displayed as per the 2nd Page but the current link at pagination numbers remains 1 which should change to 2.

Here is the code that has been implemented

```
$total = $this->bmodel->countResultsBanner();

    $data['total'] = $total;

    $uri_segment = $this->uri->segment(4);

    if($uri_segment == 0 || empty($uri_segment)){
    $uri_segment = 0;
    }

    $perPage = 5;



    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/modules/banner/index";

    $config['total_rows'] = $total;

    $config['per_page'] = $perPage;

    $config['num_links'] = 4;

    //$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b><span class="current_page">';

    //$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span></b>'; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $result = $this->bmodel->getAllBanners($perPage,$uri_segment);


    $data['result'] = $result;
```

thanks in advance.

J

Comment: Can you provide more information? The coding part

Comment: @royrui I have added the code the to initial question. Please check. Thanks J

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heyy,

I also faced the same problem. In the end, solution turned out to be very simple. :)

by default CI assumes that uri segment used for pagination is (3). Which in your case, for you  (i am  assuming  shamelessly) is incorrect.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/modules/banner/index";
$config['total_rows'] = $total;
$config['per_page'] = $perPage;
$config['num_links'] = 4;

$config['uri_segment'] = 3; /* segment of your uri which contains the page number */

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: i have worte the tutorial about Codeigniter Pagination. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/. Have a look and give your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

ok... try this...

```
$total = $this->bmodel->countResultsBanner();

    $data['total'] = $total;

/* Comment out this part
        $uri_segment = $this->uri->segment(4);

        if($uri_segment == 0 || empty($uri_segment)){
        $uri_segment = 0;
        }
    */
    $perPage = 5;



    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/modules/banner/index";

    $config['total_rows'] = $total;

    $config['per_page'] = $perPage;

    $config['num_links'] = 4;

    //$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b><span class="current_page">';

    //$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span></b>'; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

/*Change the following line*/

 $result = $this->bmodel->getAllBanners($perPage,$this->uri->segment(5));


    $data['result'] = $result;
```

Comment: I tried it... but still the error sustains. I have been trying to figure this out for past couple of hrs.

Comment: hi, when you click on the other page, how's the url looks like? Is it something like "index.php/modules/banner/index/3" ?

Comment: yes it looks like the one posted by you in the previous comment

Comment: The solution posted by you earlier is the real solution there was some problem with the code that it was not rendering.

Comment: So it function well now? Is it causing by the $config['uri_segment'] ? Your uri_segment is 5 actually

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url']="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/pagination";

$config['per_page']=2;

$config['total_rows']=  $this->db->get('record')->num_rows();
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['query']=  $this->db->get('record',$config['per_page'],  $this->uri->segment(3));
$this->load->view('pagination',$data);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['uri_segment'] = num; /* where num is the uri segment where you have page number */
```

Answer (score -1):

[Try this](http://richdadcoder.blogspot.com/2016/05/cerate-pagination-build-from-scratch.html), it might help.

```
class Admin_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function get_product($search, $page, $perpage) {
    $page = $page - 1;
    $page < 0 ? $page = 0 : $page = $page;
    $from = $page * $perpage;
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('tbl_product')
            ->limit($perpage, $from)
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
}
```