# I am getting the pagination and the page links but the links are not working properly

Tags: php

I am trying to get pagination using codeigniter. But on a page I am getting all the records from db.I want all the pages to be divided but it is not happening. I want a solution uregently. I have searched all the forums but not getting a solution.

My Controller goes like this:

```
public function catalogs()
    {

        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->model('Cataloguemodel');

        $get_vars = $this->input->get();
        if(is_array($get_vars))
        $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($get_vars,'', "&");
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . $this->router->class."/catalogs";
        $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] . (isset($config['suffix'])?$config['suffix']:'');

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Cataloguemodel->record_count();
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(3);


        $config["num_links"] = 4;

        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';



        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;


        $data['catalist'] = $this->Cataloguemodel->Cataloguelist($config['per_page'], $page);

        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('features',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

My model goes like this

```
public function Cataloguelist($limit= null, $start= null)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

        $returncataarray = array();

        $sql = "select id, name, image, catalogue, description from tbl_catalogues";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows())
        {
            $rows = $query->result();

            foreach($rows as $tempcata)
            {
                $smallcataarray = array();

                $smallcataarray['id'] = $tempcata->id;
                $smallcataarray['name'] = $tempcata->name;
                $smallcataarray['image'] = $tempcata->image;
                $smallcataarray['catalogue'] = $tempcata->catalogue;
                $smallcataarray['description'] = $tempcata->description;

                array_push($returncataarray, $smallcataarray);
            }
        }

        return $returncataarray;
    }

     public function record_count() 
    {
        return $this->db->count_all("tbl_catalogues");
    }
```

}

Views goes like this.

```
<section id="main-container">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- About us -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="article-title">Catalogues</h2>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Title row end -->

            <div class="feature-items">
            <?php
            foreach($catalist as $tempcat)
            { 
            ?>
                <h3 class="title-normal"><strong><?php echo $tempcat['name'];?></strong></h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 feature-item-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="admin/<?php echo $tempcat['image'];?>" alt="" width="200" height="200"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 feature-item-content">
                        <p><?php echo $tempcat['description'];?></p>
                         <a href="admin/<?php echo $tempcat['catalogue'];?>">Download Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                </div>



            <div class="ts-divider">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <div class="paging text-center">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li><?php echo $links;?></li>
            </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: I am getting error

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5' at line 1

select id, name, image, catalogue, description from tbl_catalogues, ,5

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/mofe/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152301/codeigniter-pagination)

Comment: I have checked that not getting the result

Comment: Also my problem is that all the records are displayed on the single page althought I have mentioned 2 per page.

Comment: please check this link

Comment: http://mofe.zinet.in/index.php?/Welcome/catalogs

Comment: PLease unhold this I am badly in need of a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```

then add limit in the query

```
$sql = "select id, name, image, catalogue, description from tbl_catalogues $start,$limit";
```

Comment: getitng and error. Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5' at line 1

select id, name, image, catalogue, description from tbl_catalogues, ,5

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/mofe/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5, 0' at line 1

select id, name, image, catalogue, description from tbl_catalogues, 5, 0

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/mofe/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me

Comment: Yes it is working but the links are not showing the rest of the contents

Comment: It should come 0,5 for the first

Comment: My issue is resolved. I am having another problem when I click on the pagination links 2 it gives be 2 in the url but on clivking 3 its is giving 4 then 8 and so on.

Comment: set in the pagination configuration                                   $config[‘use_page_numbers’] = TRUE;

By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

update you function Cataloguelist with below code

```
public function Cataloguelist($limit= null, $start= null)
    {
       $returncataarray = array();
       if($limit>0){
          $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }
        $this->db->select('id, name, image, catalogue, description', false);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_catalogues');

        if($query->num_rows())
        {
            $rows = $query->result();

            foreach($rows as $tempcata)
            {
                $smallcataarray = array();

                $smallcataarray['id'] = $tempcata->id;
                $smallcataarray['name'] = $tempcata->name;
                $smallcataarray['image'] = $tempcata->image;
                $smallcataarray['catalogue'] = $tempcata->catalogue;
                $smallcataarray['description'] = $tempcata->description;

                array_push($returncataarray, $smallcataarray);
            }
        }

        return $returncataarray;
    }
```

and update controller code too

```
$this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->model('Cataloguemodel');

        $get_vars = $this->input->get();
        if(is_array($get_vars))
        $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($get_vars,'', "&");
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . $this->router->class."/catalogs";
        $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] . (isset($config['suffix'])?$config['suffix']:'');

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Cataloguemodel->record_count();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: no still I am getting all the data in one page

Comment: what is ur url share it?

Comment: It is woking but the pagination links on clicking is not showing the rest of the data

Comment: update your controller code with given

Comment: no it still remains in the same page

Comment: means say it display 2 data then on clicking it is not showing the next 2

Comment: it is showing the first page only

Comment: if I click on the secong link the first link stays

Comment: what is the url of first page and second page share it ?

Comment: i will explain you... i am retrieving say 10 data from db. and I am displaying it to a page using pagination i.e first two will be shown den on clinking the next or any of the pagination link it should next data ri8... but only the fist link stays other pages are not coming. upon clicking on pagination link next it stays the same

Comment: update your controller please?

Comment: I have updated and shared the updated controller as well

Comment: u haven't used my code given to you please update it and remove  $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

Comment: I have used the contrller code you are referring to is the previous one

Comment: this issue is because of $config['uri_segment']  . did u used $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(3); //3 or 4 or 5 as ur url?

Comment: yes.. please check the updated controller code I have updated

Comment: can u share uri of fisrt and second link?

Comment: first and second??

Comment: on clicking the second noting is coming

Comment: I am running it on localserver

Comment: no issues, share both urls copy it and share?

Comment: http://localhost:99/mofe/index.php?/Welcome/catalogs

Comment: the url remains the same when I click on next or 2 in pagination link'

Comment: echo $this->uri->segment(3);exit; what's the value share with me

Comment: and run without question ? like this localhost:99/mofe/index.php/Welcome/catalogs

Comment: It is working fine now but the first link remains active always and the next button is not working

Comment: you there- Kool-Mind

Comment: mofe.zinet.in/index.php?/Welcome/catalogs