# Sending form data to an email codeigniter

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send form data to an email. The functions are running perfectly but email is not going to the specified email address. I am getting the response as 100 but there is no email received.

My controller:

```
<?php
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

public function sendemail()
    {
        $this->load->model('Contactmodel');

        $response=array();
        $response=$this->Contactmodel->sendemail();
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

My model

```
<?php
class Contactmodel extends CI_Model
{       
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function sendemail()
    {           
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

        $returnarray = array();
        $to_email = 'cse.akhilraj@gmail.com';
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->from($email, $name);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            $returnarray[0] = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            $returnarray[0] = 101;
        }

        return $returnarray;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    class Contactmodel extends CI_Model
    {

        public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
        }



public function sendemail()
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

                $email_to= 'cse.akhilraj@gmail.com';

                $email_subject= 'Enquiry';

                $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

                function clean_string($string)
                {
                    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }

                $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers

        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
                    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                $this->email->to($email_to);
                $this->email->from($headers);
                $this->email->subject($email_subject);
                $this->email->message($email_message);

                $returnarray = array();

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            $returnarray[0] = 100;
        }

        else

        {
            $returnarray[0] = 101;
        }

        return $returnarray;

    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No the email is not going through

Comment: var_dump($this->email->send());exit; and share the reponse

Comment: i am getting the response as bool(true)

Comment: ok kool, it's working. please check your spam too, if not using smtp.

Comment: No it is not there in the spam

Comment: No hope. no email received.

Comment: helloo you there @Kool-Mind

Comment: what's your to and from emailid's

Comment: u tried   $this->load->library('email',$config);  $config same as i gave you in answer

Comment: from: what ever is typed in the form

Comment: ok then use this   $this->email->from('akhil@zient.in'); as smtp_user checking is there and append user's email in message

Comment: and smtp_user & smtp_pass is ur email-id and password of gmail's account and from adress should be same too

Comment: Ok but where will i get the email

Comment: No still no response

Comment: did not receive any email

Comment: See it is a contact form that I am creating. The data whatever the user puts in the from should go to an email ID of the company

Comment: I have another question as well- if possible help me with dat as well. please refer that on this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033235/pagination-using-codeigniter-in-php?noredirect=1#comment65418166_39033235

Comment: So SMTP details of company should be there and from address should be same as smtp_user

Comment: how can the from be of smtp user the customer are putting there query to reach the co.

Comment: so from should customers ID ri8

Comment: No my dear you should create message and append form details there and config will have SMTP details see my answer

Comment: From email id should b in message. That's why u facing issue. Think how u can send message from user's email id

Comment: which answer.. I have pasted my model. could you please reframe it for me

Comment: OK hold on give me 5 min

Comment: please note that the message variable refers to comments that the user is putting in the from

Comment: if possible gve an answer to my this ques as well--- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033235/pagination-using-codeigniter-in-php?noredirect=1#comment65418166_39033235

Comment: It is a bit urgent. I hve to leave the offce.. could plz give a solution

Comment: check update code and append form-data in message don't try to send email from user's email u can't do this

Comment: Ok but what should I do with the email_data thing that you have commented

Comment: will you please give a solution to another ques aswell